# Bitbucket newly created remote branch is not listed

Tags: git, bitbucket

Just created a new branch in Bitbucket but I can see it neither in sourcetree nor using the `git branch -r` command. Why do you think that is? Why I can't see that branch?

Do I need at least 1 commit on this fresh branch to see it in the remote list?

After creating the remote branch (from branch X) I did:

```
git pull origin X  
git fetch --all 
git remote update
```

I also did `git config -e` fetch is defined as below for remote X:

```
[remote "origin"]
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

None of them worked. That fresh branch is still invisible.

Comment: Has the newly created branch already been pushed to remote?

Comment: I created the branch on the remote itself (on bitbucket using bitbucket gui)

Comment: Is the branch visible on bitbucket itself?

Comment: Yes it is visible on the bitbucket gui

Comment: And `git branch -a` does not list it?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen git branch -a not listing it. it should have been "--all". fixed it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> [remote "X"]
> ```

If your remote is named `X` (like your branch), no amount of `fetch` or `pull origin` will fetch or pull anything from remote "X".

Even `git fetch X` might not fetch anything if you have no remote "`origin`" (and the refspec associate with remote `X` is refs/remotes/origin/*: if you don't have an `origin`...)

Type `git remote -v` and check if `origin` is actually referencing the right repo.
If you do, `git config --local --edit` will allow you to go and change your config, fixing the discrepancy between the name of the remote and the refspec.

A `git ls-remote | grep X` can help detect if the branch actually does exist.

Comment: Very Sorry. Remote is named origin. Fixed that. An upvote for catching that error in the question though.

Comment: @SoftwareTheory Does `git ls-remote origin` list your remote branch `X`?

Comment: unfortunately that won't list it either @VonC

Comment: Then the branch is not created on the remote side. Maybe try, for testing, to create a commit on that branch through the web UI. And see if a fetch does fetch it.

Comment: I found the problem. The problem was actually me not paying attention to the branch type and seeing the branch in a huge alphabetical list of branches.

Comment: In my case `get fetch --all` didn't fetch all branches.
`git remote -v` had `origin https://username@bitbucket.org/user/repo.git`.

I did `git remote remove origin`,
`git remote add origin https://bitbucket.org/user/repo`.

Now `git fetch --all` worked and all remote branches became present

Comment: @c0ffeeartc Good tip. That would for the associated refspec (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) to be re-created. And since the default refspec is `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, that would fetch *all* branches.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the problem. The problem was actually about my being careless. The branch is created in the remote branch but I was not paying attention to the "Branch type" parameter while creating the branch in Bitbucket. `git branch -r` was listing all the branches on the remote alphabetically and I was trying to see my branch among the "feature/..." branch list but I had not created the brach as a "feature" branch type, I had created is as a "custom" branch type and it was being listed towards the top of a huge branch list without feature/ prefix. Thanks, @VonC for all the help.

Comment: Well spotted. +1. I have added in my answer the command which helps finding your branch in that huge list of remote branches.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:

Step 1: After creating new branch run this command from project directory (if you change directory earlier)

```
git fetch && git checkout <new_branch_name>
```

Step 2:

```
git add .
```

Step 3:

```
git commit -m "write your commit"
```

Step 4:

```
git push origin <new_branch_name>
```

Answer (score -1):

You may please try to push your branch to upstream using :

```
git push -u origin X
```